# Can I develope application using DirectX 11

Tags: directx, directx-11

I want to know if we can develop C#, WPF application using DirectX 11. I have an application (medium size) which is written using DirectX. We need to use features from Directx 11 like parallel rendering. Is it possible to develop applications using DirectX 11? If yes can anyone provide me some sample application for that? We can't go for other options like SlimDX as we can't afford to rewrite whole code.

Please suggest what is the best option for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried using C# with DirectX myself, but from what I've read, your main options for DirectX and C# are either SlimDX (which you count out) or XNA, which many users seem to find lacking in features, especially from the newer versions of DirectX.

Comment: Sadly, he can't go for SlimDX because of economical reasons. :( But XNA should be OK, right?